# Do hue light bulbs remember your routines after a power outage?

Tags: lighting, philips-hue

Do hue light bulbs remember your daily routines after a power outage? I noticed, for example, that when I have a go to sleep routine running, and the lights are dimmed, if I accidentally turn them off and on from the regular light switch, they turn back to full brightness and seem to forget the routine saved on my hue app (the official Philips app). Do I have to delete the routines and create them back, so that the lights have the routines in memory again?

Answer (score 7):

The Hue lights automatically turn on following a power outage, this is regarded as a safety feature. Your routine ought to be stored and should resume at the next switching point.